# Android Studio "min SDK Version" not all installed versions is available for selection

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have installed "Android API 16" in SDK Manager but I can't choose API 16 in min SDK version in Android Studio. So I can't run the project on my device. How I can change it to 16 or earlier version?

Thanks
 [image]

[image]

Comment: Just change it in android manifest file.In   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: It's exactly what I did, I can also change it manually in grandle config and it works. But why I can't  change this is Android Stuidio?

Comment: Just copy the old platform from other sdk if you have that will show all the platforms if you are unable to download this is a work around.

Comment: @piyush It is not correct. Gradle overrides this value in AndroidManifest, using the value in build.gradle.

Comment: yup that is why i asked him to add platforms in the sdk folder so that he can do it from ui view.

Answer (score 0):

You can type into that control instead of choosing one of its values. Just enter 16 and you should be good to go.